# Apple Music purchase fails

Tags: apple-id, apple-music, billing

I have 2 apple id’s with the same billing information. I try and purchase Apple Music in the new account. I get a message saying my request could not be processed. I tried changing the billing but it did not work. I added funds but it did not work. I even removed content restrictions but it failed. How do I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call or open a ticket with Apple Support so they can advise - they’ll be able to let you know how to differentiate the accounts if needed or just fix whatever issue in the back end has flagged your situation to be in error or fix an actual server side error if that’s what has happened.

They have the best insight as to which steps you can take to resolve this rapidly.